# Change parameters between javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I apologize for my bad English.
I have this code, which I would like to deposit on my ftp and I would like to create another javascript code that calls it and changes some parameters by hand.

I'll explain

The code is this that I would like to put in a file called white-label.js:

```
<script type = "text / javascript">
var CT = {
  ABE: {
    Settings: {
      clientID: 378455,
    language: 'IT',
 age: 40,
      residenceID: 'IE',
      pickupID: 11,
      leadDays: 7,
      durationDays: 7,
    }
  }
};
</ Script>
```

I would then like to create a code in js that allows me to modify for example the ClientID: 378455 line, putting for example ClientID: 909345, or modify other parameters like the language etc without changing the main code above ...

I saw this code around:

```
<div data-white-label>
   <div data-white-label-element> </div>
   <script data-white-label-config type = "application / json">
       {
           "language": "en",
           "transfers_limit": 10,
           "transfer_options": [],
           "transfer_options_limit": 12,
           "display_currency": "",
           "country": {},
           "place_from": {},
           "place_to": {},
           "max_height": 0,
           "disable_currency_selector": false,
           "hide_form_extras": false,
           "deep_link": true,
           "hide_external_links": false,
           "ref_params": {
              "pap": "5daeca246e8d8",
              "pap_bid": "e7b7ae50"},
           "scroll_offset": 0}
   </ Script>
</ Div>
<script src = "https://example.com/js/white-label.js"> </script>
```

can someone explain to me how to do it?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: do you want to store the changes permanently or just for a current running session?

Comment: Actually it is a javascript banner.
I have to give my affiliate the opportunity to change some parameters like language etc when he enters the code on his site.

So I can't answer your question exactly.

Comment: well, if I understand your question then to change the value in an object you do something like CT.ABE.Settings.age = 22;

Comment: In the code as in the question, at the age entry there is:

age: 40,

what do i put in place of 40?
that's what I don't understand

Comment: i am sorry, i do not understand, can you try to clarify?

Comment: Look at the code below
from what i understand i should put the type code like this
<Script>
var CT.ABE.Settings.language = RU;
</ Script>

but here below for example in language what do I wear?

<script type = "text / javascript">
var CT = {
   ABE: {
     Settings: {
       clientID: 378455,
     language: 'WHAT DO I USE? ',
  age: 40,
       residenceID: 'IE',
       pickupID: 11,
       leadDays: 7,
       durationDays: 7,
     }
   }
};
</ Script>

Comment: i really do not understand. but lets start with what you just typed, to change the language from ‘WHAT DO I WEAR’ to ‘RU’ then you will put CT.ABE.Settings.language = ‘RU’;